# ROS Hydro Amazon EC2

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, ros hydro, and my  computer seems to be too slow sometimes, making ros crashes.
So I'm wondering if I should use a cloud services.
Did somebody already use the Amazone EC2? If yes, did it work fine?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190687/ros-hydro-amazon-ec2/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04 on `EC2` works fine for ROS for us, except that we haven't tried graphical tools (e.g. RViz, rqt).
Just notice that in order to keep the satisfying performance you have to pay certain amount of charge.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2